# How to pass variables to page.executescript() in capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I need to pass the variable in the javascript to be executed through excute_script method in capybara.

I am unable to pass variable to it.

Please anyone help me.

Example:

```
@idd="sample"
txt=page.execute_script('var user_id = ${@idd}; return user_id;')
puts txt
```

I am expecting the text sample to be printed but i'm getting java script error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the problem is with ${}; you have to use #{}; try with:

```
page.execute_script("var user_id = '#{@idd}'; return user_id;")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now, i'm getting the result. :)